# SQL Server error "Procedure expects parameter"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm writing a login script. But when I want to check if user already exist the error:

> Additional information: Procedure or function 'checkIfUserExcist' expects parameter '@username', which was not supplied.

will show up.

When I execute the stored procedure with one parameter it will succeed. Sow there is something wrong with my code, but I can't find the mistake.

This is the stored procedure:

```
@username varchar(50)
as
begin 
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM lars.userAcces 
    WHERE username = @username
end
```

And this is my C# code:

```
public static bool checkIfUserExists(string username)
{
        int temp=0;

        SqlConnection conn = SqlConn.openSqlConnection();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("checkIfUserExists", conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

        temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();

        if (temp == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: You really should be using `using` statements around your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` so that if a exception is thrown the connection is still cleaned up. Also your `Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());` is kind of redundant, your query is already returning a int `(int)com.ExecuteScalar()` should do the same thing and be faster.

Comment: Not a direct fix for your code but you really should read this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell your `SqlCommand` that it uses a stored procedure - like this:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("checkIfUserExcist", conn);
-- add this line here
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
```